# Mixing predicate logic with propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, logic-translation

In this paper in legal philosophy (https://doi.org/10.3790/rth.40.1.1) on p. 25, the author writes:

P(x) ↔ (x → ¬h)

This is supposed to be a formalisation of the following statement: "Every utterance of an opinion x is legal as long as it doesn't violate someone's honour." ("Jede Meinungsäußerung x ist rechtmäßig, solange sie nicht gegen das Recht der persönlichen Ehre (h) verstößt.") The author explains that "x=an arbitrary utterance, h=honour"). It is not clear to me what "P" stands for but I assume it is supposed to mean "legal".

It seems to me there are several issues here.

1. The author is mixing predicate logic with propositional logic. "x" is either a variable ranging over utterances ∈ D , or it is a proposition ∈ {True, False}. It seems on the left it is supposed to be the former, on the right the latter. I think therefore, the formula is not well formed. Do I fail to understand it because it is indeed nonsense because it is not a wff?
   I think, it should rather be something like:
   P(x) ↔ ¬H(x)
2. However, this formula still does not seem to capture the meaning of the ordinary language sentence appropriately. Rather, it should be:
   ∀x(¬H(x) → P(x)) or ∀x(¬P(x) → H(x)) respectively.
   That, however, is false, as a matter of fact, because not violating someone's honour is not a sufficient condition for being an admissible utterance. Rather it is a necessary one. Thus, the correct formula would be, I think:
   ∀x(P(x) → ¬H(x)) or ∀x(H(x) → ¬P(x)) respectively.
3. The negation indicates that "h" (and my predicate "H") represent not "honour", as the author states but rather "violation of honour". At least if "P" means "legal".

I would be grateful if you could clarify whether I am confused or the author (and reviewers) of this indeed respectable journal.

Comment: You are correct the statement should be made in predicate logic

Comment: P(x) is a predicate; thus x is an individual variable. Thus, x → ¬h is wrong.

Comment: having said that, we can use propositional variables in FOL: a possible example is P(x) ↔ (Q(x) → ¬H)

Comment: Can we? See this is exactly what confuses me. It would mean we have two domains, one consisting of objects (a,b,c,...; and sets A, B, C,... of them; and relations R, S, T,... on them) and another domain consisting of propositions (h in the original example or H in yours). I have never encountered such a thing. Could you recommend any literature on this?

Comment: I would very much appreciate a clarification if anyone can help.

Comment: We can treat them as zero-place predicates: $H()$ This will behave the same as propositional variables in propositional logic, but is in line with the syntax and semantics of predicate logic.

Comment: That said, what they wrote is clearly wrong, and I wouldn't trust anything of what they have to say about logic in that paper.

Answer (score 4):

> Every utterance of an opinion $x$ is legal as long as it doesn't violate someone's honour

My translation is $$\forall x{\in}O\;\Big(\,¬\exists y{\in}P\,H(x,y)→P(x)\Big);$$ equivalently, $$\forall x{\in}O\,\exists y{\in}P\;\Big(\,¬H(x,y)→P(x)\Big).$$

- $H(x,y):$ uttering opinion $x$ violates person $y$'s honour
- $P(x):$ uttering opinion $x$ is legal

Comment: Thank you, both of you. Can you confirm that P(x) ↔ (x → ¬h) is not a well-formed formula?

Comment: Yep, that's not a wff. BTW, my translation uses the shorthand $∀x{∈}X\:F(x)$ to mean $∀x\:[x{∈}X\to F(x)].$